# Serialization in Saxon-HE XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I'm performing json to json transformation using XSLT..

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "file1.xml",
        "value": [
            {
                "data1": [
                    {
                        "data2": [
                            {
                                "data3": [
                                    {
                                        "data4": [
                                            {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag1": [
                                                    "fg"
                                                ],
                                                "tag2": [
                                                    "ss"
                                                ],
                                                "tag3": [
                                                    "df"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

To sort the tags inside json objects I'm tried using saxon:property-order.. but in my case it won't support.

Because I'm using Saxon-HE 10.01 version.

Here is my xslt styleSheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jlib="http://saxonica.com/ns/jsonlib"
xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"

version="3.0">
<xsl:param name="input"/>
<xsl:output method="json"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-copy"/>

<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes" saxon:property-order="tag1 tag2 tag3"/>
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
<xsl:variable name="in" select="parse-json($input)"/>

<xsl:variable name="out" as="map(*)*">

<xsl:for-each-group select="$in?*" group-by="?fileName">
<xsl:map>
<xsl:map-entry key="'fileName'" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
<xsl:map-entry key="'value'" select="map{'data1':array{map {'data2':array{map {'data3':array {map{'data4': array:join(current-group()?value?*?data1?*?data2?*?data3?*?data4)}}}}}}}"/>
</xsl:map>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:sequence select="array{$out}"/>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the below exception from the java code:-

Error at xsl:output on line 11 column 516
XTSE0020  Serialization parameter Q{.../saxon.sf.net/}property-order is not available in Saxon-HE

How to use property-order in saxon-he 10.. Or any other functions in saxon-he to perform the property-order mechansim/sorting mechanishm?

Comment: With Saxon, most extensions to the XSLT and XPath standards, are only available in the commercial editions PE and/or EE so if the extension is part of the commercial editions, you won't find them in the open-source HE edition. As for your question about other ways, I think I pointed out in an earlier question that the XML representation of JSON that XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 use with `xml-to-json` and `json-to-xml` do preserve that order of properties and any sorting done on the XML representation to change the order will be preserved when you use `xml-to-json` on the transformation result.

Comment: Martin if I want display in certain order means tag3,tag2,tag1 in that time how your sylesheet works.

Comment: As I said, work with the XML representation of JSON the XSLT 3.0 and the XPath 3.1 spec defines, transform/reorder the XML as needed and in the final step use `xml-to-json`, that way any order of items in the XML will be preserved when converting to JSON.